# Java: error code 53 when creating user in Active Directory by Ldap

Tags: java, active-directory

i am trying to create an active User in Windows Active Directory by ldap in java.

my creation method is:

```
private Attributes createUserAttributes(String userName, String firstName, String lastName, String password) {
    Attributes container = new BasicAttributes();
    Attribute objClasses = new BasicAttribute("objectClass");
    Attribute userPassword = new BasicAttribute("userPassword", password);
    Attribute sAMAccountName = new BasicAttribute("SAMAccountName", userName);
    Attribute userPrincipialAttribute = new BasicAttribute("userPrincipalName", userName + "@" + DOMAIN_NAME);
    Attribute firstNameAttribute = new BasicAttribute("givenName", firstName);
    Attribute secondNameAttribute = new BasicAttribute("sn", lastName);
    Attribute activatedAccount = new BasicAttribute("userAccountControl", "512");

    objClasses.add("user");

    // Add these to the container
    container.put(objClasses);
    container.put(userPassword);
    container.put(sAMAccountName);
    container.put(userPrincipialAttribute);
    container.put(firstNameAttribute);
    container.put(secondNameAttribute);
    container.put(activatedAccount);

    return container;
}
```

Unfornutately i get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.naming.OperationNotSupportedException: [LDAP: error code 53 - 0000052D: SvcErr: DSID-031A120C, problem 5003 (WILL_NOT_PERFORM), data 0
```

Has anyone ideas ?

Comment: Please, complete the error with the stack

Answer (score 1):

This will help answer your problem [Thread: Operation Not Supported Exception in JNDI/Active Directory](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=1157956) also [How to add an active user account to Active Directory](http://www.forumeasy.com/forums/thread.jsp?tid=134931028635&fid=ldapprof9&highlight=How%20add%20active%20user%20account%20Active%20Directory).

Answer (score 1):

The problem for me was the password relevance. With a weak password, the same message was shown. Verify what are the rules defined on AD.